# What keyboard key does one use for "@" with a Pi?

Tags: keyboard

When I type @ I get " instead. I have tried different keyboards, but this is obviously a Pi issue. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try going into Menu > Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration > Localization > Set Keyboard, and set it according to where you live.